# How to play Windows' Steam games from Linux?

Tags: windows, wine, games, steam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I run Steam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1784/how-can-i-run-steam)

I have two partitions, one with Windows 7 and all my games and another with Ubuntu.

I want to play my Windows Steam games without having to download all the games in my Linux Steam.

Is it possible ?

Comment: This question is NOT a duplicate. It asks for a very specific usage case, different from simply installing Steam on Linux: How can you run Windows Steam games using the Linux Steam?

Answer (score 2):

Steam have no native version in Gnu/Linux. Maybe you want to install it by Wine or PlayonLinux. Your Steam games are installed on your Windows partition, because Steam did it. Of course, you can mount your Windows partition on Ubuntu, and launch your game manually by double-clicking on the .exe which will be using Wine. In my opinion, if you run on a dual-boot, it is better to run your Windows Steam games on Windows, because Wine is a good solution for apps like Office 2007 or Internet Explorer which does not require a good configuration, but if you want a good experience when playing a game, just don't use Wine, and play on Windows.

Comment: This is simply not true. Lots of Steam games work pretty well over Wine, TF2 for example works great.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But if he wants to play with no bugs, playing games on Windows is better.

Comment: If you want to play with **no** bugs, you'll be hard pressed to find a game that will suit that need. Anyway, the asker was asking about Wine, so I don't think 'use Windows' is a good answer.

Comment: By "no bugs", I meant "bugs which does not exist when playing the game natively". Anyway, he did not mention Wine, it was me. He asked "I have two partitions, one with Windows 7 and all my games, and other with Ubuntu.

I want to play my Windows Steam games without having to download all the games in my Linux Steam.

Is it possible ?"

So my answer is "Yes, but because he have a dual/boot, playing on Windows is a better solution."

Comment: Yes he did. Look at the tags. And what does it matter whether the bugs exist when playing natively? Every game has bugs, it's just a matter of whether they are game-breaking or not. Even in Wine, a lot of games are very playable.