# What is HLDS and what is it for?

Tags: steam

I currently use two computers, one is windows 7 and mainly for gaming, and the other is running 11.10, when i was on Steam browsing today i noticed that at the bottom of the steam page you can click on a drop-down named "tools" and under it it says "Linux HLDS update tool" clicking on it brings up a download.

Does anyone know what this is for? Is this a patch for a Steam-Linux application that i am unaware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HLDS stands for Half-Life Dedicated Server: afraid it's nothing to do with running Steam on Linux, just running a server for Half-Life 2 engine-based games (Counter-Strike, TF2, etc).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you can install Steam on Ubuntu 11.10 using Wine and here is a guide on it:

[How can I install Steam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1784/how-can-i-run-steam)

And here is how games work (Left 4 Dead 2):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjhcDK8Khx8

Or you can take a look at Desura, a Steam-like games platform that supports officially Linux:

http://www.desura.com/