# Will Ubuntu allow me to play games like I do in Windows?

Tags: wine, games

I was wondering if Ubuntu would let me play games like a Windows7 computer would.

ie:Team Fortress 2, Minecraft, etc

Comment: Impossible to answer since it depends on your hardware. Please add in more detail. Specifically the graphics card is important if 'wine' is needed to run the game. For all of those games you can also visit http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=category&iId=&sAction=view&sTitle=Browse+Applications  and see what kind of problems you might face.

Comment: When checking the site keep in mind some games will probably work within Wine, they just haven't been added to the site because users haven't posted them. Also Valve will move more and more games towards Ubuntu as they are working on getting Steam running: [as confirmed here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/valve-confirm-steam-left-4-dead-2-coming-to-ubuntu)

Comment: Both Team Fortress 2, and Minecraft have native Linux versions. So no problem.

Answer (score 5):

Simple answer: **No**. You can get some to run, but a lot more won't run, many will also run badly. If gaming is a priority for you, the easiest fix is to just dual boot into Windows. If you are really lucky, the handful of games you care about might run in Linux (e.g. Minecraft does).

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu can run Minecraft, or any other Java based game natively, as long as you have Java installed onto your machine
Just right click on the installer and choose to open the file with either (whichever you have installed) the Open JDK or the Oracle Java versions

With most other game binries, it needs to be emulated inside a package called Wine, which emulates the Windows repositories so that the program thinks it is running in Windows. The link to the download and install page for Ubuntu is [here](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu)

For flash games you need a browser to be able to run them

Answer (score 2):

Depends a lot on the games you want to run and on your graphics card driver.

Ubuntu depends on Wine to run Windows native software, Wine emulates a virtual environment while allowing the programs to access your system's hardware directly. Wine is not perfect and will not run everything, to check if an application can run in Wine using Ubuntu please visit the [`WineHQ`](http://appdb.winehq.org/) page and search for the software you want to run.

If your graphics card can use OpenGL and the used drivers for your card are installed and active then there should not be much of an issue there. Again, depends on the hardware you have installed and the driver you are going to use.

While Wine is the backend that allows you to play games on Ubuntu some tricks might be needed to make a couple of programs/games run, developers have made it easy for you to install such software using a frontend for Wine, one of those is [`PlayOnLinux`](http://www.playonlinux.com/en).
What it does is you will choose the application from a list that you want installed on your Ubuntu system, POL will then apply any other necessary applications to a Wine bottle and then install the application itself, most of the times that is all that it is necessary.

[*PlayOnLinux* [image: Install playonlinux]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/playonlinux) (click on the link) is probably the easiest free way of installing Windows software in your Ubuntu system.

Nothing is 100% prof using Wine, so the easiest way to testing if an application runs in your Ubuntu system is really giving it a try. Both applications that you gave as an example in your post run and have good support in Wine, it should not take much of an effort for you to install them in your system.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install it through Wine ,both are rated as **GOLD**  as here

[Team Fortress 2](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=9901)

and [Minecraft](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26019)

For other details read [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/163931/63025)

For list of other games that are available see http://appdb.winehq.org/

Answer (score 0):

As well as running some Windows games in Wine (as people have been talking about), there are some great native Linux games that will run well if you have full opengl acceleration for your graphics drivers. In the repositories, ready for install, there is a great game called [Alien Arena](http://red.planetarena.org/media.html), which uses the crx game engine and has impressive visuals. There are quite a few other shooters like this available and most such as [Nexuiz](http://www.nexuiz.com/) (again in the repos) can be played online.

Neverwinter nights can be run natively on Linux and not just through wine, but it takes a while to set up and there isn't space to go into it here; however, there is a [launcher](http://icculus.org/~ravage/nwn/) which might work with some versions of the game, or, more likely, you may need to set it up manually, as I did for a friend.

A lot of games can be played in the browser now as well, a notable one being [quake live](http://www.quakelive.com/), and there are many other ones available, which other answers have mentioned.

(I won't mention much about Dosbox or scummvm, as I think you said you want to play more modern games, but those emulators are available in the repositories and support many old games)