# How to play games using Wine?

Tags: wine, games

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will Ubuntu allow me to play games like I do in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165425/will-ubuntu-allow-me-to-play-games-like-i-do-in-windows)
>   [Installing and running games](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166173/installing-and-running-games)

I install game after game through Wine but not one game will play after installation. Do I need to install more apps or do games just not work on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: You need to specify which games you are talking about to get any help.

Answer (score 6):

http://appdb.winehq.org/ has an extensive list of games and apps that work with wine. Any games that are listed as platinum or gold for your version are worth trying out.

Answer (score 4):

Some examples of games that work on wine with minimal configuration (according to the appdb, the site [Marcel's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/167678/22949) mentions):

- StarCraft I
- Guild Wars
- Left 4 Dead
- Counter-Strike
- The Sims 3
- Warcraft III The Frozen Throne
- Command & Conquer 3: Tiberium Wars
- Bioshock 1.0
- Portal
- Portal 2