# Any way to check the clock speed of my processor?

Tags: cpu

Is there any way to check at which clock speed my processor is running?

I have already tried `cat /proc/cpuinfo` but the clock speed I'm running isn't showing. I know Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) requires 700 MHz and VGA, but will an AMD Mobile Sempron work?

Comment: You need more specific on the second part of your question. Do you know the model number?

Comment: Thank you for all the answers but I am good now!

Answer (score 292, accepted):

From the command line type `lscpu`. The information will be at CPU MHz:

```
~$ lscpu | grep MHz
CPU MHz:               804.901
CPU max MHz:           3200.0000
CPU min MHz:           800.0000
```

Comment: Note that the value of CPU MHz is not fixed and may change by the second.

Comment: Is there something like that embedded into something like `htop`? Something similar to Performance Monitor in Windows?

Comment: @Royi `watch "(lscpu | grep MHz)"`

Comment: grep Hz to also find GHz

Comment: `lscpu` did not show freq for me. `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep MHz` worked

Answer (score 226):

There are a couple of ways:

1. `lscpu` or more precise `lscpu | grep "MHz"`.
   This will give you the general MHz for the CPU.

   ```
    $ lscpu | grep "MHz".
    CPU MHz:               1600.000
   ```
2. `cat /proc/cpuinfo` or more precise `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "MHz"`.
   This will give you the individual MHz for each CPU Core. So if you have an Core 2 Duo, AMD Bulldozer, Core i7, etc.. it will show the MHz for each core.

   ```
   $ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "MHz"
   cpu MHz     : 1600.000
   cpu MHz     : 1600.000
   cpu MHz     : 1600.000
   cpu MHz     : 1600.000
   cpu MHz     : 1600.000
   cpu MHz     : 1600.000
   cpu MHz     : 1600.000
   cpu MHz     : 3400.000
   ```
3. `lshw -c cpu` or more precise version:  `lshw -c cpu | grep capacity`
   Will give you the general MHz. Same as `lscpu`.

   ```
   $ lshw -c cpu | grep capacity
   WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
          capacity: 1600MHz
   WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
   ```
4. `sudo dmidecode -t processor` or more precise: `sudo dmidecode -t processor | grep "Speed"` Will not only give you a MHz in use but also the Maximum you can push / overclock your CPU to.

   ```
    $ sudo dmidecode -t processor | grep Speed
    [sudo] password for cyrex: 
        Max Speed: 4000 MHz
        Current Speed: 2666 MHz
   ```

Out of all of this, `lshw` and `dmidecode` provide the best information out of your CPU.

You can also target the current MHz detected by the kernel by querying the log files:

`cat /var/log/dmesg | grep "MHz processor"` - For the current detected MHz speed

`cat /var/log/kern.log | grep "MHz processor"` - For the current and past detected MHz speeds. Will not work in some cases, that is why I posted the `dmesg` one first.

And that's all I can remember from the top of my head. I am fairly certain there are other ways, just don't remember right now. Of course, talking about terminal ways.

**Note:** All the commands above will also give you the CURRENT cpu Hertz, meaning, if you expect to see the same one on `lscpu` and when doing the `cat /proc/cpuinfo` it will be near impossible. you CAN compare the maximum because that should show the same for any of the ways you can analyze the CPU, but the current will always be literally "the current CPU hertz" at the moment you execute it. Lastly do note that dmidecode reads information from the ACPI tables which is not always the same as the real time ones done by the other tools.

Comment: For me, all options except dmidecode gave a false reading: I'm overclocking an intel E6600 2.4ghz chip on a gigabyte ga-965p-ds3 3.3 board with 7x multiplier & 400mhz CPU frequency to give 2.8ghz CPU, but the stock multiplier is 9 (9x266=2.4ghz) so I suspect the rest of the tools assume multiplier is stock and times that by the CPU mhz, so in my case they all give 3.6ghz.

Comment: `dmidecode` seems to be the only one to accurately report the clock speed when overclocking

Comment: @AvindraGoolcharan Actually that is very good to know. Thank you.

Comment: `lscpu` gives me max and min frequency, but not the current one. `cat /proc/cpuinfo` tell me lots of stuff about my ARM cores, but no frequency at all. `lshw` doesn't exist. `dmidecode -t processor` gives me an unhandled fault. Those may work on your PC, but not on my embedded linux. `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq` is the way to go.

Comment: On my system with an Intel Core i5-7200U (base frequency 2.5 GHz; Turbo Boost up to 3.1 GHz) and Ubuntu 16.04, this is what I see. (I used `... | grep Hz` to easily find these.)
`lscpu`: "Model name: ... 2.50GHz" (base), "CPU MHz: 624.796" (current), "CPU max MHz: 3100.0000" (turbo).
`lshw`: "product: ... 2.50GHz" (base), "capacity: 3100MHz" (turbo).
`dmidecode`: "Version: ... 2.50GHz" (base), "Max Speed: 2500 MHz" (base), "Current Speed: 2400 MHz" (some value from DMI table).

Comment: Note that the information from `dmidecode` generally can't be trusted to be accurate for your system because it just reads data from the DMI tables, which may be wrong. The man page for dmidecode even says the information is "possibly unreliable", and goes on: "The DMI table doesn't only describe what the system is  currently  made of,  it  also  can  report the possible evolutions (such as the fastest supported CPU or the maximal amount of memory supported)." "More often than not, information contained in the DMI tables is inaccurate, incomplete or simply wrong."

Comment: `dmidecode` doesn't seem to work, it shows the CPU stuck at max frequency, which is not accurate, I'm pretty sure. `powertop` and `lscpu` show the actual variable frequency.

Comment: You don't need to `cat /path/to/file | grep "some string"` - you can just `grep` the file directly instead: `grep "some string" /path/to/file`. Awesome answer, though.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400002/determining-the-clock-speed shows strange results... would you know why?

Answer (score 112):

For the current CPU speed one can dynamically watch this change in real time using:

```
sudo watch -n 1  cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
```

To see the maximum CPU speed, use:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
```

Comment: +1, I know this is an Ubuntu site, but this appears to be the only answer providing a command that is completely OS independent.

Comment: If you get Permission Denied trying to read scaling_max_freq, try cpuinfo_max_freq.

Comment: `cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq` doesn't exist

Comment: +1, even on several ARM-based systems running Ubuntu only this solution works. Each and every other "solutions" given on this page fail there, while this works everywhere.

Comment: On my system I need to use `scaling_cur_freq` as the filename, not `cpuinfo_cur_freq` which no longer seems to exist. So the full command is: `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq`

Comment: intel_pstate CPU freq driver doesn't provide `cpuinfo_cur_freq`.  `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver` to see what driver is currently used.  BTW, `cpuinfo_cur_freq` is hardware's point of view and `scaling_cur_freq` is kernel's point of view of the current CPU frequency. More on https://static.lwn.net/kerneldoc/admin-guide/pm/cpufreq.html#policy-interface-in-sysfs

Comment: Please mention units. Note that the units appear to be in kHz, so a maximum CPU speed of `3800000` is `3800000 kHz`, or 3.8 Ghz.

Answer (score 19):

[indicator-cpufreq-selector](https://launchpad.net/indicator-cpufreq) is a nice little indicator tool which shows your current CPU frequency. You can even select the desired CPU frequency.

[image]

However, the last update for this tool was on [2021-05-28](https://code.launchpad.net/indicator-cpufreq).

Comment: You can install it using `sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq`.

Comment: And after installing, you'll need to reboot before it will show up.

Comment: Doesn't work well in newer Ubuntus, if at all.

Comment: Where does it show the 'desired cpu frequency'??

Comment: @france1 The little dot next to the options indicates the current desired frequency. Click on other options to switch.

Answer (score 15):

This works fine for real-time processor speeds

```
 watch "grep 'cpu MHz' /proc/cpuinfo"
```

While this is active, you can also spam the processor to see what maximum real-time speeds it can reach by `openssl speed`

Answer (score 9):

I would just like to add [`i7z`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/i7z.1.html) to this list. Contrary to the other options, this works better for CPUs in the i7, i5 and i3 series that have TurboBoost.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. And it also shows Vcore voltages, Turbo multipliers, C0 halts, etc. Very nice!

Comment: Heads up, requires 30mb of ruby and assorted tools.

Answer (score 9):

This is my favorite:

```
watch -n1 "grep 'MHz' /proc/cpuinfo"
```

Although if you have Turbo Boost (or Turbo Core if AMD), you may prefer the following, which uses `cpupower` from the [linux-tools](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/linux-tools-common) group:
<sub>* On my system, both work equally well though.</sub>

```
sudo watch -n 1 -d cpupower monitor
```

Thanks [@Zanna](https://askubuntu.com/users/527764/zanna) for point out the useless use of `cat` in the comments.

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to point out `sudo` is needed for Ian's answer above:

```
sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
```

However you can get the same results without sudo using:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
```

My favourite is to use Conky where you can paint your own picture:

[image: Conky.gif]

This sits on the right of my built-in display all the time. The relevant code for the CPU section is:

```
${color2}${voffset 5}Intel® i-7 3630QM 3.4 GHz: ${color1}@  ${color green}${freq} MHz   
${color}${goto 13}CPU 1 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu1}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu1 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 2 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu2}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu2 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 3 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu3}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu3 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 4 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu4}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu4 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 5 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu5}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu5 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 6 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu6}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu6 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 7 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu7}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu7 18}
${color}${goto 13}CPU 8 ${goto 81}${color green}${cpu cpu8}% ${goto 131}${color3}${cpubar cpu8 18}
${color1}All CPU ${color green}${cpu}% ${goto 131}${color1}Temp: ${color green}${hwmon 2 temp 1}°C ${goto 250}${color1}Up: ${color green}$uptime
```

Comment: Where is *Conky* and what is it?

Comment: @not2qubit I'll update this answer later but in the meantime see this Arch Linux article: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/conky

Comment: Is there something like that built in for Ubuntu?

Comment: @Royi Like most Ubuntu applications you can install conky with `sudo apt install`. Then you design your system monitor display anyway you like. I built mine using bits and pieces of examples others have for conky. You can do a google search on `conky` to see what's out there.

Comment: Are there pre defined recipes?

Comment: @Royi I've posted the conky "recipe" above in another Q&A: https://askubuntu.com/questions/604720/setting-to-high-performance/1047763#1047763

Answer (score 5):

If you are using an embedded ARM device (such as a Raspberry or ARM based phones), you will not be able to use solutions using `lscpu`, `dmidecode` or `/proc/cpuinfo` because the current speed is not listed there, if the tool is at all available. Instead you have to use *sysfs*:

```
alias getcpuf='i=1; for x in $(sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq); do y=$(($x/1000)); echo "CPU-${i}: $y MHz"; i=$((i+1)); done;'

# getcpuf
CPU-1: 600 MHz
CPU-2: 600 MHz
CPU-3: 600 MHz
CPU-4: 600 MHz
```

Answer (score 4):

`sudo powertop` then hit Tab twice to get to the "Frequency stats" tab.

It displays Actual frequency (accurate on my Laptop, as opposed to `dmidecode`), along with stats about how long is spent in each available frequency.

Comment: Does it have a specific line for the current frequency? Looks to just show the % of time each frequency + idle state is "active", no indication of which is active right now?

Comment: @Xen2050 CPU frequency can change back and forth within milliseconds, so I'm more interested in statistics. You can run `powertop -t 1` for a low delay, so that stats will be updated every second.

Answer (score 3):

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies
```

Comment: This does not show the current frequency

Answer (score 3):

Here is a straightforward way to get cpu frequencies for all CPU threads:

1. Be sure that `cpufrequtils` is installed.
2. Then in a terminal, run the following command:

   ```
   cpufreq-info | grep "frequency is"
   ```

Answer (score 2):

In a terminal, enter:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep name
```

It should display the exact model of your CPU.

This [Wikipedia page on the Sempron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_Sempron_microprocessors#Mobile_Sempron) will give you detailed specifications.

Comment: This does not show the current cpu frequency

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to share this as a comment, but dont have many reputations on askubuntu, People who want to use  indicator-cpufreq do not need to reboot the  computer. Resetting the current X session is enough to display the icon.

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq   
DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace
```

You can validate the Performance and Powersave option by seeing the current frequency by

```
watch -d "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i Mhz"
```

As soon as you click on a lower frequency / Powersave, the powermanagement of the CPU kicks in, thereby reducing the clock cycle.

Comment: The user logging out & in again (but not rebooting) would probably work as well

Answer (score 2):

In a Linux terminal type the following command to get the CPU core name and it's current speed:

`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -E "model name|cpu MHz";`

Answer (score 1):

The gnome tweak Vitals shows to my mind more accurately to 2.5 (even 2.7Ghz) of my Ryzen 2500, others showed 2Gz. ( pdfsandwich OCR'ing a pdf file is a good tester as it maxes out all CPUs)

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1460/vitals/

Answer (score 1):

Please note that [/proc/cpuinfo contains wrong values](https://serverfault.com/questions/704456/cpufreq-info-differs-from-proc-cpuinfo). Because of that I use this:

```
watch -n2 "cpufreq-info | grep 'current CPU'"
```

Result:
[image]

And here the wrong result of /proc/cpuinfo:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 22.04 no longer provides the current CPU speed in lscpu without the extra flags -ae so to get the **average** cpu speed I have a cpuspeed script in /usr/local/bin/:

```
data=`lscpu -ae | cut -c 61-69 | grep -iv MHz`
total=0.001
count=0
while read -r line
do
    total=`awk "BEGIN {z=$total + $line; print z}"`
    let count+=1
done <<< $data
avg=`echo $total / $count | bc`
echo $avg
```

All it does is print out the average cpu speed in MHz. If you want to continually monitor it, call it from watch.

Whilst I like *i7z* this produces the number without having to install anything or having lots of other stuff around it.

(assigning 0.001 to total is my hack to ensure that the floating point math works and I'm sure everyone will criticise me for have three different math methods in 3 lines! Please don't bash my Bash)

Answer (score 0):

Sample output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 69
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x17
cpu MHz     : 774.000
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
bogomips    : 3591.40
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 69
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x17
cpu MHz     : 1600.000
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
bogomips    : 3591.40
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 69
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x17
cpu MHz     : 800.000
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
bogomips    : 3591.40
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 69
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x17
cpu MHz     : 774.000
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 3
initial apicid  : 3
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
bogomips    : 3591.40
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Here `cpu MHz` means current cpu frequency.
You can run `cpufreq-info` to understand easily.

Comment: redundant and long !

Answer (score 0):

run command `sudo i7z`, the benefit of this command is it will tell real time cpu frequency with other information like temperature as well.I used to use `sensors` for temperature but it showed one time temperature. This command start a process with shows real time information.

Comment: This same utility was suggested by someone else in an answer from five years ago 