# How to really check current cpu Hz?

Tags: cpu

All programs I've tried seem to be listing Hz from cpu's specifications not actually checking what the current Hz really is.

for example a processor is marketed with 4GHz.But this is the max (unless you over/under/clock) and if the cpu isn't doing anything or is getting too hot it will throttle down.

The program always will say 4Ghz even when the CPU is at 2Ghz.I want to avoid this and know the real Hz.

What programs actually check current cpu hz and not just read cpu specifications?

Comment: I want the program to show the Hz in realtime if possible.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/218567/any-way-to-check-the-clock-speed-of-my-processor ( sudo dmidecode -t processor | grep "Speed" )

Comment: @Rinzwind I like this the most because it displays cpu hz ever ysecond. `sudo watch -n 1  cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
` but I dont have cpu folder in cpu folder so I get no such file or directory.What should I do?

Comment: ok but I would added it to the link 3 people accepted as duplicate ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can easily check the current CPU frequency using the following command:

```
watch -n 0 "lscpu | grep 'MHz'"
```

You can also get the current cpu frequency with this command:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
```

Most modern CPUs can adjust their clock frequency. The default governor on linux is "on demand" which keeps the clock speed low to save power when idle, and speeds it up to do work when needed.

Visit https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/governors.txt for further details.

Comment: Is the governor not working? I always see 2000MHz.

Comment: open close several applications, start VMs, it will change. Or maybe close all of them and wait a couple seconds to see the idle speed

Comment: I really mean always (unless I overclock)the same even if cpu usage is 100%

Comment: Try forcing the powersave mode with `echo "powersave" >/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`

Comment: There is a small exception..: some programs show the Hz as 2000.xxx where xxx is different on every boot (I guess boot) now it is 2000.175 Why does the xxx number change?

Comment: ok I will try it.How to revert to normal? EDIT: No such file or directory

Comment: replace `powersave` with `ondemand`, See the kernel doc for supported values (like performance)

Comment: Unofrtunately I couldnt try it because I get No such file or directory every time.Why is this?

Comment: `cat: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq: No such file or directory` for a `AMD Ryzen 5 3600 (12) @ 4.706GHz`

Comment: The path on my system is `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_cur_freq` and `/sys/bus/cpu/devices/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq`