# Will installing TLP noticeably change Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, battery, tlp

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a MacBook, and am considering installing `TLP` to improve battery life/overheating.

But I'm curious if it will change brightness settings/Internet or Bluetooth functionality, things like that.

Anything I would notice or could potentially annoy me? I'm hoping it's just a somewhat silent background program, is this the case?

Comment: Look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/512905/what-exactly-is-tlp-doing-that-default-system-config-wouldnt) for your (hopefully) answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoted from http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html

> TLP applies these settings automatically on startup and every time you
>   change the power source. To use it, all you have to do is install TLP,
>   however, there are some settings that you can apply manually,
>   overwriting the TLP default settings, such as enabling or disabling
>   the WiFi, Bluetooth or Wwan (3G or UMTS) radios, switching between AC
>   or battery settings, ignoring the actual power source, apply
>   autosuspend for all attached USB devices or power off the optical
>   drive.

As a conclusion it will affect wifi,bluetooth, Wwan, ... and need some manual configuration.

If you prefer some daemon apps for controlling overheat, then try installing [thermald](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues) with

```
sudo apt-get install thermald
```

Quoted from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues

```
Thermald

The thermald daemon prevents machines from overheating and was introduced in 
the 14.04 Ubuntu Trusty LTS release. It monitors thermal sensors and will 
modify cooling controls to keep the hardware cool. Thermald uses the 
available CPU temperature sensors and will keep the CPU from overheating. If 
hardware supplies a skin temperature sensor then by default thermald will 
endeavour to keep the skin temperature under 45 degrees C.
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, It looks like TLP will disable WiFi and Bluetooth until needed, and it also controls brightness.

Quick answer: yes.