# dmidecode showing Memory Module Voltage: 3.3 V for DDR3 RAM

Tags: ram

I see

```
$ sudo dmidecode -t 17
...
        Memory Module Voltage: 3.3 V
...
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 1600 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Asset Tag: Asset Tag:
    Part Number: M471B5273CH0-CK0
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 533 MT/s
...
```

**What voltage is 3.3v?** (surely not the spec of the SODIMM)

**How can I tell the spec of the SODIMM from the CLI?**
(I am not seeing `Configured Voltage: xxxx V` in the output of `dmidecode` as others quote).
As per several links found using the part no. *Samsung M471B5273CH0-CK0* ([1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DUG7AU4), [2](https://memory.net/product/m471b5273ch0-ck0-samsung-1x-4gb-ddr3-1600-sodimm-pc3-12800s-dual-rank-x8-module/), etc.), it is 1.5v.

Comment: It looks like your ddr3 is ddr2, at least according to "Configured Memory Speed: 533 MT/s" .

Comment: 3.3v would be an LP (Low Power) SODIMM, which was all the rage about 10 years ago.

Comment: @mikewhatever - That very low "Configured Memory Speed" was also surprising to me, and I was going to ask another question.
But all the indications, manufacturer (Toshiba) specs for the PC, manufacturer (Samsung) specs for the SODIMM part no., etc., suggest this is DDR3... Please see EDITed OP.

Comment: @matigo - Ok.
1) Does it tell anything about the SODIMM voltage? (1.35v or 1.5v)
2) Is 3.3v the voltage in the bus? or what else?