# Connection failed message when installing wine

Tags: installation, 12.10, wine

When installing Wine in 12.10 I get the following message:

```
Err http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main fonts-unfonts-core all 1.0.3.is.1.0.2-080608-5ubuntu1
  Connection failed
Failed to fetch http://np.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fonts-unfonts-core/fonts-unfonts-core_1.0.3.is.1.0.2-080608-5ubuntu1_all.deb  Connection failed
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Did you try running `apt-get update` as the message says and installing wine again?

Comment: I would first invite you to read this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/163903/gaming-performance-difference-between-windows-7-and-ubuntu/163931#163931

Answer (score 1):

For that type of error do the following:

`sudo apt-get update`

The update should finish without any errors. If it has an error about failed connection, try it again. Keep doing this until it finishes correctly.

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

Same as above. If it has a failed connection error, do it again until it finishes.

`sudo apt-get install wine1.5`

Again, same as above. The problem for this might be connection problems, repository updates in progress, Internet issues or Godzilla in your backyard.