# What to do if connection failed during installation

Tags: installation, wine

I got the following error while installing Wine from the Terminal.

```
Err http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/multiverse wine-gecko1.4 amd64     1.4.0-0ubuntu2                                                                         
  Connection failed [IP: 41.73.43.3 80]
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ precise/main wine1.4-amd64 amd64 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4                                                     
  Connection failed
Err http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/multiverse wine-gecko1.4 i386 1.4.0-0ubuntu2                                                                          
  Connection failed [IP: 41.73.43.3 80]
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ precise/main wine1.4-i386 i386 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4
  Connection failed
```

It is installing everything else fine, it just seems to be a select few files that it is not able to download for some reason. Why is this? And what should I do from here to fix the install? Rerun the command in the Terminal?

I apologise if this seems simple or common knowledge but I honestly have no idea what to do from here, as a completely new Ubuntu user.

If there is a way to 'clean up' this action and reverse what I have done that may also be great. I could then just use the Ubuntu Software Center to download and install Wine.

I am running Ubuntu Studio 12.04

Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while downloading. Check the following thread:
https://askubuntu.com/a/277520/249322