# Low FPS with Radeon HD4570

Tags: wine, performance, framerate

I need some help with my FPS in League of Legends. Right now I'm getting as low as 9 FPS in team fights and 30fps max when I'm alone - that's running the game on lowest settings at 1024x768. Meanwhile on Widows I was getting 30-60 at 1080p low/med settings.

I've tried several versions of wine and different drivers but it doesn't seem to change.

Here's the specs (really old)

- Intel Pentium T4200 (2ghz dual core 64bit)
- Ati mobility radeon HD 4570 (512mb gddr3, shader 4.1, dx10.1, 680mhz core/800mhz memory)
- 4 GB RAM,  DDR2
- Ubuntu 16.10

PS. It's weird, a friend of mine had a laptop with worse specs (Intel GPU) he played on Ubuntu and his performance was fine he even played ranked with no problems

Comment: Current Intel Graphics, even those in the entry level Celeron and similar are more powerful than an old ATI card.

Comment: The intel graphics card i mentioned was from a laptop bought in the same year as mine

Comment: Wine is a Windows emulator and comparing performance between an emulated platform and a native platform is like comparing apples to celery. They are both crunchy, but the similarity ends there. You don't mention what version of wine you are using  which may have [an impact](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163903/gaming-performance-difference-between-windows-and-ubuntu) Note that 16.10 while currenlty supported will reach End Of Life in just a [few short months](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) so it might be prudent to move to an LTS version for longer support (16.04).

Comment: This may also be of interest to you. https://www.winehq.org/search?q=League+of+Legends.

Comment: I saw that yeah, i gave up though was getting frustrated, i'll just go without league for a couple months till. Buy my new laptop