# How to configure Wine for Half-Life?

Tags: windows, wine, configuration, games

Hi, I've been trying to run Half-Life 1 on Ubuntu 12.10 with Wine. The game starts to the menu OK, but when the actual game starts nothing happens. I can't move, only my mouse works, and the game is not in full screen. Can someone show me how to configure Wine to run it?

Comment: I'd recommend you to look at this question:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/129664/how-do-i-install-half-life-1-and-2-on-ubuntu-12-4

Comment: You don't need to use Wine anymore! Half-life 1 has been released for native Linux!

Comment: @Ysangkok, do you have a link?

Comment: @NathanJ.Brauer: http://steampowered.com . register your CD key in steam if you didn't already

Answer (score 2):

In the menu under options, make sure to use OpenGL as the video renderer instead of DirectX. Once I did this, I required no additional wine configuration and everything worked fantastic.

Comment: This. I've had the same problem and I figured out that I just need to change the video mode.

Comment: Yeah, this works (using Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 0):

Only for steam half life and only for video card with `Graphic Drivers: nVidia 310, AMD 12.11` the requirements for linux is more than windows. For this I use wine.