# None of my games are working in wine 1.5

Tags: 12.10, wine, games

I have been trying to download and play World of Warcraft, and play Stronghold (disk game) but neither are working. My wine is version 1.5.28. I have seen on WineHQ's AppDB that both work for others, so i ask, what would i need to do to get them both to work?

Comment: Can you execute the games from the terminal and let us know what the output is. For example type "wine Wow.exe" inside the World of Warcraft folder. Also type "wine --version" to see your actual version.

Comment: wine version 1.5.28m And with WoW, i can go onto the updater, but it doesn't get to the "playable" section

Comment: Please add what the error shows when you run wine Wow.exe on the game folder.

Comment: it says, "The program World of Warcraft Setup.exe has encountered a serious problem and needs to close We are sorry for the inconvenience."

Answer (score 0):

Ok since your error is very general, I am going to give you the following links which I have updated to solve some of the problems you might be having:

To install Wine follow this link: [How do I install wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15518/how-do-i-install-wine)

To configure wine with additional packages that are needed to have a working Game follow this link: [How do I install Half-Life 1 and 2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129664/how-do-i-install-half-life-1-and-2?lq=1)

To be able to use wow and other apps follow this link: [Adjusting resolution for individual Wine programs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16733/adjusting-resolution-for-individual-wine-programs)

And to correctly solve many of the video problems follow this link: [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/which-driver-should-i-install-when-using-an-nvidia-ati-or-intel-video-card)

With this, you should be set to a working Wow (And many other games for that matter)

Comment: Where can i get the Audio Drivers needed? as i used the simple "Test Sound" feature on winecfg and it came up with the same message