# Video Card not detected in Steam on Wine

Tags: nvidia, graphics, wine, steam

I am new to Linux and was hoping someone can help me get Shogun 2 up and running in Steam which was downloaded via PlayonLinux. Currently, the game installs and shows a license screen briefly before it shuts down with no error message.

In the System Info tab, Steam does not seem to detect my video card though the nVidia drivers have been installed and my computer recognizes the card (GeForce GT610). Maybe there is another issue though. Any help would be most appreciated! if useful, I have an ASUS M5A97 motherboard and running Ubuntu 12.04,

The system info Steam shows follows:

Processor Information:
    Vendor:  AuthenticAMD
    Speed: 4200 Mhz
    4 logical processors
    1 physical processors
    HyperThreading:  Supported
    FCMOV:  Supported
    SSE2:  Supported
    SSE3:  Supported
    SSSE3:  Supported
    SSE4a:  Supported
    SSE41:  Supported
    SSE42:  Unsupported

Network Information:
    Network Speed:

Operating System Version:
    Windows XP (32 bit)
    Wine version: wine-1.4.1
    NTFS:  Supported
    Crypto Provider Codes:  Supported 323 0x0 0x0 0x0

Video Card:
    Driver Not Detected

```
DirectX Driver Name:  nv4_disp.dll
Driver Version Not Detected
DirectX Driver Version:  6.15.12.6658
Driver Date Not Detected
DirectX Card: NVIDIA GeForce 8300 GS
VendorID:  0x10de
DeviceID:  0x423
Number of Monitors:  1
Number of Logical Video Cards:  1
No SLI or Crossfire Detected
Primary Display Resolution:  1440 x 900
Desktop Resolution: 1440 x 900
Primary Display Size: 15.00" x 9.37"  (17.68" diag)
                                        38.1cm x 23.8cm  (44.9cm diag)
Primary Bus Type Not Detected
Primary VRAM Not Detected
Supported MSAA Modes:  2x 3x 4x 5x 6x 7x 8x 9x 10x 11x 12x 13x 14x 15x 16x
```

Sound card:
    Audio device:

Memory:
    RAM:  7933 Mb

Miscellaneous:
    UI Language:  English
    Microphone:  Not set
    Media Type:  CD-Rom
    Total Hard Disk Space Available:  1861779 Mb
    Largest Free Hard Disk Block:  720019 Mb
    OS Install Date: May 08 2010
    Game Controller: None detected

Installed software:
    Adobe Flash Player 11 Plugin
    Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable
    Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.21022
    Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.17
    Sid Meier's Civilization V
    Steam
    The Witcher: Enhanced Edition
    Total War: SHOGUN 2
    Wine Gecko (32-bit)

Comment: Allot of AAA titles will not run on the Linux version of Steam. I have run into the same issue. I am still working on it, but I believe the answers lie some were in installing the correct libraries inside of wine.

Answer (score 1):

I will start my answer saying, I maybe wrong. But, I looked at your Device ID in PCI database. But, There's no card for 0x423. But 8300 GS's ID is 0x0423. So, I think this is a counterfeit card. Please install this card under Windows with a Driver Downloaded on NVIDIA's official site. If the offcial driver (download from nVidia site only) can be detected with your your card, you are safe. (don't use drivers that came with your card.) I know this because it happened to me. Most counterfeit cards use fake IDs that close to actual card. (in this case 8300 GS, not 610GT)

Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hadn't noticed that. I don't think it's the problem though because I got the nVidia driver version 304.43 directly from the website and my computer recognizes the card as a GT 610 - Only Steam is showing the version as 8300 GS. Is there a way to trick Steam into recognizing the correct drivers or should I try reactivating them? Would uninstalling Steam work? And if so, is there a way to do that without having to download all the games again? Thanks!

Comment: I don't use steam, so I can't answer about steam. But linux nvidia driver detects counterfeit cards. Only windows driver can't recognize them.

Answer (score 1):

Why need to use Steam on Wine? They now have Steam for Ubuntu, which you can easily install with an [apt-get command or ubuntu software centre](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1784/how-can-i-install-steam). You should be able to install the .deb file for beta [here](http://store.steampowered.com/about/). This will work on your machine much better than running an exe on wine.

Comment: on a side note, you can add the linux driver for your nvidia card by going into settings > drivers and it should prompt you about using a proprietary driver on your system. Install the according deb accordingly, this may be a short way out of your problem.