# Launch Steam games without a X Desktop running

Tags: games, desktop-environments, steam, fullscreen, .desktop

I'm using [the first, accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/418718/22949) to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302488/can-i-run-steam-as-its-own-standalone-session/418718) to have Steam as an Environment on Login.

Steam itself works fine, but when I attempt to start a game, the screen turns black and I have to restart LightDM service to be able to login again...

How do I launch a game when there's no Desktop Environment running, just LightDM and Steam in BigPicture mode?

I've tried to start DotA2 and Super Hexagon, but both times the screen turns black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need have a window manager running.
If you don't know how, there's a project for what you want to do:
[steam big picture xsession](https://github.com/thor27/steam-login/)

Answer (score 1):

[Steam Login](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/better-steam-for-linux-performance-with.html) will launch you directly into BPM and also reduce overhead on your processor.