# Steam says I am missing 32-bit libraries

Tags: steam, 32-bit, libraries, glibc

When I install Steam I get:

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: 
libc.so.6.
```

How do I run

Comment: Did you install Steam from the Software Centre ? if so then it should have installed the 386 libraries alongside it.  If not, remove what you have and reinstall from the software centre.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Steam?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1784/how-can-i-install-steam)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following commands in a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
mv ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1{,.disable}
mv ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6{,.disable}
```

When steam has started then update and you might want to use the commands again.