# How to install left for dead 2 in Ubuntu?

Tags: games

I have tried a lot to run this game in my Ubuntu PC but still I cannot run it. I have also tried it with WINE but the game was not running properly and it was taking more and more time to start and after installing it my PC was working slow. So any one can please give me the perfect idea about how to install it?

Comment: The easiest would be to install it natively through Steam.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Steam?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1784/how-can-i-install-steam)

Answer (score 1):

*Left for Dead 2* plays natively on Ubuntu with the **Steam client**.
I'm unsure why you would need **Wine** unless you have a physical disk for **Windows**. *Left for Dead 2* is a source based game, which is known to have **bad performance in Wine**.