# Can I play Unturned on Steam on Ubuntu?

Tags: games, steam

I want to play Unturned on Steam. Is Steam compatible with Ubuntu or more specifically does it work with Unturned?

Comment: It's probably less a question of compatibility with Ubuntu and more of compatibility with your graphics card and specific drivers. I have an amdgpu (combined cpu+graphics) and it works to some extent but not fully. IME most games need a more powerful setup to run under Linux as they're not well optimised and less work goes in to bug fixing than does for other OS. In short YMMV. Steam discussions often have good info in this respect though. You should include details of your system to get a better response (eg via Steam > Help > System Information).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Steam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1784/how-can-i-install-steam)

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from the [Steam store page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/304930/Unturned/), Unturned supports SteamOS/Linux, so yes you can play it on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can install SteamOS or just Steam on your Ubuntu installation, then install "Unturned" as it does display being compatible with both. However, like pbhj had pointed out in the question comments, it's more of a concern of whether or not your hardware can support it. Like they mentioned, games on non-windows platforms like Ubuntu are often overlooked in regards to compatibility, so your mileage will vary. The only way you'll know is if you install the game and it works or not.