# Steam stuck at verifying installation on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: steam

I installed Xubuntu on an old laptop (**Fujitsu Amilo Pro v2060**) that sports a Pentium M 735A and an Intel Mobile 915GM/GMS/910GML GPU (copy-pasted from terminal after running `lspci | grep VGA`).

I tried to install steam via the `.deb` package from the official website, and everyting went smoothly until the *Verifying installation* phase, which terminates without anything else happening. Here's the terminal output:

```
lazaros@AegonIV:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 32-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522709999)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522709999)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522709999)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522709999)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1522709999)
assert_20180411132825_1.dmp[11756]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20180411132825_1.dmp
/home/lazaros/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 927: 11746 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
assert_20180411132825_1.dmp[11756]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20180411132825_1.dmp[11756]: response: CrashID=bp-39dbb9b2-1bf5-4902-89b9-1987a2180411
assert_20180411132825_1.dmp[11756]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20180411132825_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-39dbb9b2-1bf5-4902-89b9-1987a2180411''
```

[Here's](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RWkpOW8PNtTVFWEGKtOVxUmMZsbYCgnV) the minidump file.

I don't know how to read the dump file and I have no idea what to do now, so I am asking for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Steam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1784/how-can-i-install-steam) or [Problem with installing Steam on Ubuntu 15.04+](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614422/problem-with-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04)