# Hogwarts Legacy on steam doesn't work

Tags: 22.04, snap, games, steam

I have Ubuntu 22.04 and wanted to open a game on Steam but it immediately crashed so I looked at the whole thing with journalctl and discovered these errors:

```
Feb 01 17:20:49 GamingPCderPIs kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 16 callbacks suppressed
Feb 01 17:20:49 GamingPCderPIs kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1706804449.357:491428): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/5189/environ" pid=39034 comm="steam" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:52 GamingPCderPIs Steam Linux Runtime 3.0 (sniper).desktop[39034]: /bin/sh\0-c\0/home/pi-gaming/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=990080 -- /home/pi-gaming/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-launch-wrapper -- '/home/pi-gaming/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/SteamLinuxRuntime_sniper'/_v2-entry-point --verb=waitforexitandrun -- '/home/pi-gaming/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Proton 8.0'/proton waitforexitandrun  '/home/pi-gaming/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Hogwarts Legacy/HogwartsLegacy.exe' -SaveToUserDir -UserDir="Hogwarts Legacy" RADV_PERFTEST=gpl\0
Feb 01 17:20:52 GamingPCderPIs Steam Linux Runtime 3.0 (sniper).desktop[50427]: ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/pi-gaming/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Feb 01 17:20:52 GamingPCderPIs Steam Linux Runtime 3.0 (sniper).desktop[50428]: ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/pi-gaming/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
Feb 01 17:20:52 GamingPCderPIs Steam Linux Runtime 3.0 (sniper).desktop[50429]: ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/pi-gaming/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Feb 01 17:20:52 GamingPCderPIs Steam Linux Runtime 3.0 (sniper).desktop[50429]: ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/pi-gaming/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Feb 01 17:20:52 GamingPCderPIs Steam Linux Runtime 3.0 (sniper).desktop[50430]: ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/pi-gaming/snap/steam/common/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Feb 01 17:20:52 GamingPCderPIs Steam Linux Runtime 3.0 (sniper).desktop[39034]: (steam:39034): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion `source != NULL' failed
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/4742/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/5189/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/28967/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/46975/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/46975/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/39154/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/4742/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/5189/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/28967/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/46975/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/46975/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/39154/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/4742/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/5189/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/28967/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/46975/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/46975/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/39154/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1706804453.005:491429): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/4742/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1706804453.005:491430): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/5189/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1706804453.005:491431): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/28967/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1706804453.005:491432): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/46975/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1706804453.005:491433): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/46975/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1706804453.005:491434): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/39154/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1706804453.005:491435): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/4742/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1706804453.005:491436): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/5189/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1706804453.005:491437): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/28967/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/4742/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/5189/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/28967/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/46975/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/46975/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/39154/environ" pid=39034 comm="IPC:CSteamEngin" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs Steam Linux Runtime 3.0 (sniper).desktop[50448]: sh: 1: xdg-user-dir: not found
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs Steam Linux Runtime 3.0 (sniper).desktop[39034]: (steam:39034): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion `source != NULL' failed
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50429]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d/" pid=50429 comm="pressure-vessel" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50429]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/etc/vulkan/implicit_layer.d/" pid=50429 comm="pressure-vessel" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50459]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/" pid=50459 comm="x86_64-linux-gn" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50461]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" pid=50461 comm="x86_64-linux-gn" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50461]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" pid=50461 comm="x86_64-linux-gn" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50461]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" pid=50461 comm="x86_64-linux-gn" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50461]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" pid=50461 comm="x86_64-linux-gn" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50461]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" pid=50461 comm="x86_64-linux-gn" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50461]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" pid=50461 comm="x86_64-linux-gn" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50461]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" pid=50461 comm="x86_64-linux-gn" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50461]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" pid=50461 comm="x86_64-linux-gn" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50461]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" pid=50461 comm="x86_64-linux-gn" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50461]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" pid=50461 comm="x86_64-linux-gn" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50461]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" pid=50461 comm="x86_64-linux-gn" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50461]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" pid=50461 comm="x86_64-linux-gn" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50461]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" pid=50461 comm="x86_64-linux-gn" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50461]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" pid=50461 comm="x86_64-linux-gn" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50461]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" pid=50461 comm="x86_64-linux-gn" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50461]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" pid=50461 comm="x86_64-linux-gn" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50461]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/" pid=50461 comm="x86_64-linux-gn" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50461]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/" pid=50461 comm="x86_64-linux-gn" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs pressure-vessel-wrap[50429]: W: "snap/steam/171/graphics/usr/share/libdrm" is unlikely to appear in "/run/host"
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs pressure-vessel-wrap[50429]: W: "snap/steam/171/graphics/usr/share/libdrm" is unlikely to appear in "/run/host"
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs pressure-vessel-wrap[50429]: W: "var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/drirc.d" is unlikely to appear in "/run/host"
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs pressure-vessel-wrap[50429]: W: "snap/steam/171/graphics/usr/share/drirc.d" is unlikely to appear in "/run/host"
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs pressure-vessel-wrap[50429]: W: "var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/nvidia" is unlikely to appear in "/run/host"
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs pressure-vessel-wrap[50429]: W: "var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/nvidia" is unlikely to appear in "/run/host"
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs audit[50475]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mount" class="mount" info="failed perms check" error=-13 profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/newroot/var/pressure-vessel/ldso/" pid=50475 comm="pv-bwrap" fstype="tmpfs" srcname="tmpfs" flags="rw, nosuid, nodev"
Feb 01 17:20:53 GamingPCderPIs pressure-vessel-wrap[50475]: bwrap: Can't mount tmpfs on /newroot/var/pressure-vessel/ldso: Permission denied
Feb 01 17:20:54 GamingPCderPIs Steam Linux Runtime 3.0 (sniper).desktop[39034]: (steam:39034): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion `source != NULL' failed
Feb 01 17:20:54 GamingPCderPIs Steam Linux Runtime 3.0 (sniper).desktop[39034]: Uploaded AppInterfaceStats to Steam
Feb 01 17:20:54 GamingPCderPIs Steam Linux Runtime 3.0 (sniper).desktop[39034]: (steam:39034): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion `source != NULL' failed
Feb 01 17:20:54 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/5189/environ" pid=39034 comm="steam" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:54 GamingPCderPIs Steam Linux Runtime 3.0 (sniper).desktop[50476]: sh: 1: xdg-user-dir: not found
Feb 01 17:20:55 GamingPCderPIs Steam Linux Runtime 3.0 (sniper).desktop[39034]: (steam:39034): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion `source != NULL' failed
Feb 01 17:20:56 GamingPCderPIs Steam Linux Runtime 3.0 (sniper).desktop[50477]: sh: 1: xdg-user-dir: not found
Feb 01 17:20:59 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/5189/environ" pid=39034 comm="steam" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:20:59 GamingPCderPIs kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 38 callbacks suppressed
Feb 01 17:20:59 GamingPCderPIs kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1706804459.365:491476): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/5189/environ" pid=39034 comm="steam" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:21:04 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/5189/environ" pid=39034 comm="steam" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:21:04 GamingPCderPIs kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1706804464.401:491477): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/5189/environ" pid=39034 comm="steam" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:21:09 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/5189/environ" pid=39034 comm="steam" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:21:09 GamingPCderPIs kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1706804469.441:491478): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/5189/environ" pid=39034 comm="steam" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:21:14 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/5189/environ" pid=39034 comm="steam" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:21:14 GamingPCderPIs kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1706804474.472:491479): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/5189/environ" pid=39034 comm="steam" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:21:19 GamingPCderPIs audit[39034]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/5189/environ" pid=39034 comm="steam" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Feb 01 17:21:19 GamingPCderPIs kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1706804479.504:491480): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.steam.steam" name="/proc/5189/environ" pid=39034 comm="steam" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

I now know that it probably comes from Snap, but unfortunately I don't know much about it.
Do you know anything about these errors or how I can fix them?
I thank you in advance.

Comment: Posting truncated log messages removes their value. "`

Answer (score 0):

The aa-logprof tool will parse the AppArmor messages and suggest policy rules which would permit application to run under confinement.

```
$ sudo aa-logprof
```

[Apparmor](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/beginning-apparmor-profile-development#5-using-aalogprof-to-refine-the-profile)

or disable apparmor using the "aa-teardown" command

Comment: I tried this command but nothing changed

Comment: install  Steam through the package manager rather than using snap or disable Apparmor

Comment: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/steam-call-for-testing/34575

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1503385/881336